# What is difference between using sudo in playbook and task?

Tags: sudo, ansible

If I would like install something using e.g apt I can create playbook:

```
- hosts: xxx
  roles:
     - my-role
```

And in tasks/main.yml in role:

```
- name: install something
  sudo: yes
  apt: "name=something state=installed"
```

But, I can add sudo in playbook:

```
- hosts: xxx
  sudo: yes
  roles:
     - my-role
```

And remove it from tasks:

```
- name: install something
  apt: "name=something state=installed"
```

Both solutions work, but which solution is better? Is difference between this solutions? Pros? Cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider the *principle of least privilege*. A user or a process should have the lowest level of permissions needed to accomplish a designated task.
For example, if all you need to do is to upload a file into your home directory, doing it as root is an overkill. If you want to push a new application version, do it as a web user rather than root.

When you specify `sudo:` at a playbook level, all tasks underneath will run at that (potentially unnecessary) permission level. Whereas if you specify it at `task:` level, only that specific task will run as root.

Comment: I might add is the possibility that a case may have 9 out of 10 tasks requiring escalated permissions in which case refactoring to the playbook level might feel less repetitive.  You may also want to check out the change in syntax of become and become_user over sudo.  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html